Issue with circular density using ggplot
In my dataset,
I have a observed bird and their direction, ranging from 0 to 360, which correspond to birds heading towards North.
To represent this, I want to make a circular density plot attached here.
The issue here is that their is a pick to 0 that does not represent the actual data.
Could someone help me out ?
Here is my code :
ggplot(echo %>% filter(!is.na(direction)), aes(x = direction)) +
geom_density(fill = "grey", adjust=0.5) +
coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 2*pi) + # Polar coordinates for circular plotting
labs(x = "", y = "Density", title = "Bird Direction") +
scale_x_continuous(
limits = c(0, 360), # Ensure the x-axis spans 0 to 360 degrees
breaks = c(0, 90, 180, 270), # Set the x-axis breaks at N, E, S, W
labels = c("N", "E", "S", "W") # Label breaks as compass directions
) +
theme(
axis.text.y = element_blank(), # Remove y-axis numbers
axis.ticks.y = element_blank() # Remove y-axis ticks
)


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Probably duplicate. Check this question.
